# Apache2 redirect foo

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I searched a bit and because the folder I am trying to redirect is a subfolder of itself, it seems to be a challenge for me. Specifically here is the file system (using Apache2). I'm trying to do this with the root .htaccess file.

Apache root is .../www/

I have a subfolder .../www/foo/www/...

Within the foo/www/ are the files for this virtual site. So for example (again file system) exists
/www/foo/www/index.html

What I'm trying to achieve is a redirect from apache2's root so that request to:

```
http://'host'/foo
```

arrive at /www/foo/www/

Help is of course much appreciated.

Comment: I tried: RedirectMatch 301 ^/foo/?$ /foo/www

Answer (score 0):

Add this rule in your `/www/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^((?!foo/www/).*)$ /foo/www/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Nope, but thank you. If you can break down the logic maybe I can sort it.

Comment: Do you already have any current rules in root .htaccess OR `/foo/www/.htaccess` if yes then provide them in your question. Also is this some PHP/CMS framework?

Comment: Only rules are to require passwords when not on the local subnet. I removed it for testing. No framework.

Comment: And what URL did you try to test it? Did you get 404?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I just hate certain sloppiness ... I'm quite guilty.

Let me say thank you to those that spent the time to try and help.

Turns out from trying to make it work I had a

```
/www/foo/www
/www/Foo/www
```

when I discovered and correct this, the following worked fine:
    RedirectMatch 301 ^/foo/?$ /foo/www

although it does show the redirect in the browser URL. It is a local app so I can live with the ugliness.